# Localstack Testcontainer for Test Classes in Spring Boot (Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, testcontainers, localstack

I have a problem about working with localstack with aws for test process in my Spring Boot  example.

When I click any test of homecontroller, I got this issue shown below.

```
com.amazonaws.services.secretsmanager.model.ResourceNotFoundException: Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret. (Service: AWSSecretsManager; Status Code: 404; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException; Request ID: null; Proxy: null)
```

I think localstackcontainer cannot start before calling its exections.

How can I fix it?

Here is the baseintegration class shown below.

```
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = BaseIntegrationTest.Initializer.class)
public class BaseIntegrationTest {

public static final String LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME = "localhost";
public static final String LOCALSTACK_REGION = "eu-west-3";
public static final String LOCALSTACK_ACCESS_KEY = "test";
public static final String LOCALSTACK_SECRET_KEY = "test";

private static LocalStackContainer localStackContainer = new LocalStackContainer()
        .withServices(LocalStackContainer.Service.S3)
        .withServices(LocalStackContainer.Service.S3)
        .withServices(LocalStackContainer.Service.SECRETSMANAGER)
        .withExposedPorts(4566, 4566)
        .withEnv("HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL", LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME)
        .withEnv("DEFAULT_REGION", LOCALSTACK_REGION)
        .withEnv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", LOCALSTACK_ACCESS_KEY)
        .withEnv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", LOCALSTACK_SECRET_KEY);;

static {
    localStackContainer.start();
}

static class Initializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        String localStackHost;
        try {
            localStackHost = initializeLocalStack();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

        TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(applicationContext,localStackHost);
    }
}

private static String initializeLocalStack() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    localStackContainer.execInContainer("aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 secretsmanager create-secret --name aws/secret --secret-string '{\"my_uname\":\"username\",\"my_pwd\":\"password\"}'");
    localStackContainer.execInContainer("aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566  s3api create-bucket --bucket bucketname --region eu-west-1 --create-bucket-configuration LocationConstraint=eu-west-3");
    final Integer mappedPort = localStackContainer.getMappedPort(4566);
    return "cloud.aws.secrets-manager.end-point.uri=http://localhost:" + mappedPort;
}
```

}

Here is the BaseRestControllerTest shown below

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public abstract class BaseRestControllerTest extends BaseIntegrationTest {
}
```

Here is the homecontrollerTest shown below.

```
class HomeControllerTest extends BaseRestControllerTest {

}
```

Comment: are you using https://github.com/awspring/spring-cloud-aws?  If so, I don't think that's the right property

Answer (score 0):

Some improvements to your actual code.

1. Use `.withServices(LocalStackContainer.Service.S3, LocalStackContainer.Service.SECRETSMANAGER)`
2. Don't need those

```
.withExposedPorts(4566, 4566)
.withEnv("HOSTNAME_EXTERNAL", LOCALSTACK_HOSTNAME)
.withEnv("DEFAULT_REGION", LOCALSTACK_REGION)
.withEnv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", LOCALSTACK_ACCESS_KEY)
.withEnv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", LOCALSTACK_SECRET_KEY);
```

I'm not quite sure the localstack images contain `aws cli` but they have `awslocal` instead. Replace `aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566` by `awslocal`. Also, if using cli from another container you need to use the mapped port instead of `4566`.

See [this example](https://github.com/eddumelendez/testcontainers-localstack/blob/main/secretsmanager/src/test/java/com/example/secretsmanager/SecretsmanagerApplicationTests.java).

Comment: I have another issue regarding aws not running with localstack in docker-compose. Can you help me ? Here is the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363198/cannot-run-sh-file-regarding-aws-configure-in-localstack-in-docker-compose-yml